# Knockout SimpleGrid with radio button list in one column

Tags: knockout.js

For my first knockout.js project, I decided to keep things simple and create a SimpleGrid with a column that contains a radio button list.

I can display a radio button list using a custom template but cannot get the value selected.

There are 2 things I am trying to do now.

1. Give unique names to the radio list for each table row. Currently, all the radio buttons on all the rows have the same name.
2. Return the selected radio value in the button click event.

**HTML Code**

```
<div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel, simpleGridTemplate: "custom_grid_template"'></div>

<script type="text/html" id="custom_grid_template">
    <table class="ko-grid table table-bordered table-condensed table-nowrap" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
                <th data-bind="text: headerText"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsOnCurrentPage">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
                <!--ko if: typeof rowText == 'object' && typeof rowText.action == 'function'-->
                <td>
                    <button data-bind="click:rowText.action($parent)">action</button></td>
                <!-- /ko -->

                <!--ko if: headerText == 'Status'-->
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="checked: rowText.status" value="A" type="radio" name="statusGroup" />A
                    <input data-bind="checked: rowText.status" value="B" type="radio" name="statusGroup" />B
                    <input data-bind="checked: rowText.status" value="C" type="radio" name="statusGroup" />C
                </td>
                <!-- /ko -->

                <!--ko ifnot: headerText == 'status' || (typeof rowText == 'object' && typeof rowText.action == 'function')-->
                <td data-bind="text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText] "></td>
                <!--/ko-->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

**JS Code**

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.defaultPageSize = 4;

    self.currentPage = ko.observableArray();
    self.pageSize = ko.observable(self.defaultPageSize);
    self.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.comments = ko.observableArray();
    self.sorttype = "asc";

    self.currentPage = ko.computed(function () {
        var pageSize = parseInt(self.pageSize(), self.defaultPageSize);
        var startIndex = pageSize * self.currentPageIndex();
        var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
        return self.comments.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    });

    self.nextPage = function () {
        if (((self.currentPageIndex() + 1) * self.pageSize()) < self.comments().length) {
            self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() + 1);
        }
        else {
            self.currentPageIndex(0);
        }
    }


    self.previousPage = function () {
        if (self.currentPageIndex() > 0) {
            self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() - 1);
        }
        else {
            self.currentPageIndex((Math.ceil(self.comments().length / self.pageSize())) - 1)
        }
    }

    self.sortTable = function (viewModel, e) {
        var orderProp = $(e.target).attr("data-column")
        self.comments.sort(function (left, right) {
            leftVal = left[orderProp];
            rightVal = right[orderProp];
            if (self.sortType == "asc") {
                return leftVal < rightVal ? 1 : -1;
            }
            else {
                return leftVal > rightVal ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });

        self.sortType = (self.sortType == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc";
    }

    self.markApprove = function (comment) {
        //1
        alert(comment.author);
    }

    self.markDelete = function (comment) {
        //2
        alert(comment.author);
    }

    self.show = function (element, ww, ee) {
        //alert($(element));
        //alert($(parent));
        $(element).show();

    }

    self.hide = function (element, ww, ee) {
        //element.hide;
        $(element).hide();
    }
}

var vm = new viewModel();
vm.comments([
    { videoid: 1000, title: "Item 1", commentid: 10, comment: "Well Done!", author: "Fred", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" },
    { videoid: 2000, title: "Item 2", commentid: 11, comment: "Good Job!", author: "Bill", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" },
    { videoid: 3000, title: "Item 3", commentid: 12, comment: "Nice Work", author: "Fred", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" },
    { videoid: 4000, title: "Item 4", commentid: 13, comment: "Fantastic", author: "Bill", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" },
    { videoid: 5000, title: "Item 5", commentid: 14, comment: "Splendid", author: "Fred", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" },
    { videoid: 6000, title: "Item 6", commentid: 15, comment: "Nice....", author: "Bill", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" },
    { videoid: 7000, title: "Item 7", commentid: 16, comment: "Great", author: "Fred", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" },
    { videoid: 8000, title: "Item 8", commentid: 17, comment: "Job well done", author: "Bill", commentdate: "@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()", status: "" }
]);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

This is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u4Ymb/3/) to my jsfiddle version, showing where I am up to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Binding context for unique name and value of selected radio button.

*1. For Unique Name*
:- Use "attr" data-binding and give name property like :-

```
attr:{name:'sizeGroup'+ $parentContext.$index()}
```

*2. For Getting value of selected radio button*
:- Make another observable property for each record in grid that will store the value of selected radio button and in checked binding you have to use that observable.

```
//Selected Observable
{ name: "Well-Travelled Kitten",selected:ko.observable(), sales: 352, price: 75.95, size:["a","c","b"]}

//html binding
<input data-bind="checked: $parent.selected,attr:{name:'sizeGroup'+ $parentContext.$index()}" value="a" type="radio" />A
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4Ymb/4/)

Comment: In the jsfiddle example the data is a hard coded json data.  In a _real_  application the data is retrieved via an ajax call.

`$.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/admin/comments/GetData")", function (data) {
    ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(data));
});`

How do add an observable property to json?  Or would you add it to the observablearray?

Comment: @DavidRobinson you can use KO mapping plugin or manually you can add observable to each record before binding to observable.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  You have answered my questions perfectly.

Comment: I didn't use the $parentContext. part but this answer rejiggered my memory on how to fix the issue I was having.